# How to Draw Outer border over image bitmap?

Tags: android, kotlin, matrix, bitmap, paint

I am using 2 bitmaps, One for, Image and second for, Border.
For Outer Border I used, matrix and paint, to Draw Storked bitmap into, onDraw function.
I used below code and I got [this output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9yqj68lxnfdylmy/record-2022-02-09-14-57-19-42084ece4c769937d48a172925602669_QJlDJphX.mp4?dl=0)

```
if (drawBorder == 1) {
    val mCurrentScale = getCurrentScale()

    val imageBitmapWidth = mCurrentScale * mBorderBitmap!!.width
    val borderBitmapWidth = mCurrentScale * (mBorderBitmap!!.width + (dpToPx(mBorderSize) * 2F))
    val imageBitmapHeight = mCurrentScale * mBorderBitmap!!.height

    if (baseWidth == 0F)
        baseWidth = imageBitmapWidth
    if (baseHeight == 0F)
        baseHeight = imageBitmapHeight

    mBorderMatrix.set(bitmapMatrix)
    mBorderMatrix.postScale(
        borderBitmapWidth / baseWidth,
        borderBitmapWidth / baseWidth,
        centerX, centerY
    )
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBorderBitmap!!, mBorderMatrix, borderPaint)
}
```

You can see in this Video, the border it will increase inner and outer both side. but I want only Outerside. Please help me.

Comment: No need to use mBorderBitmap to implement the border. You know the position of the bitmap, right? So just use canvas.drawRect();

Comment: @simon5678, Yes, you are right, but when I try to rotate like sticker, Rect will not rotate according to Image bitmap.

Comment: You can use:  canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(45);
canvas.drawRect(r,paint);
canvas.restore();

Comment: Hi, @simon5678, Issue solved, Thank you for the help....